# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: How to check finished status code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, http-status-codes, sendasynchronousrequest

So I have some code like so:

```
@interface RequestHandler()

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger statusCode;

@end

@implementation RequestHandler

- (bool)sendRequest:(NSString *)surveyorId withData:(NSData *)requestData
{
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:true];

    if (self.statusCode == 200)
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Clearly the routine will carry on into the `if-else` statement before the request has finished. Therefore, `self.statusCode` is not set properly in the delegate `didReceiveResponse` before it is checked. What would be the best way of doing this?

I am just thinking of adding another `bool` property that will be set in `connectionDidFinishLoading` and then loop until this property is set. Once it has done that, then it will check `self.statusCode`. However I am thinking this will block the thread will it not? It will be no different from a `sendSynchronousRequest` right? Is there any way to do this without putting it into a background thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement 2 delegate methods:

1. **Status code**: `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response`
2. **Received data**: `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
   didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`

*Example usage:*

**Declaration**

```
@interface RequestHandler : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
}
```

**Request**

```
- (void)sendRequest:(NSString *)surveyorId withData:(NSData *)requestData
{

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

  // Apply params in http body
  if (requestData) {
      [request setHTTPBody:requestData];
  }

  [request setURL:url];
  NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
  [connection start];
}
```

**Delegates**

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didReceiveResponseCode:)]) {
        [self.delegate didReceiveResponseCode:responseCode];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(connectionSucceedWithData:)]) {
        [self.delegate connectionSucceedWithData:receivedData];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make it clear but I do have these two delegate methods implemented. They work as expected but in my ```sendRequest``` method, the ```if-else``` statement executes before the delegate methods are called.

Comment: Of course this happen, because the delegates will be called when the request is finished (it is async). So this `if clause` should be placed in the delegate: `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response`

Comment: But thes delegate method returns void. I have another class that calls this ```RequestHandler``` class that needs to know the outcome of the request.

Comment: Yes thats why you should implement your delegates `didReceiveResponseCode` in the viewController that makes the call. In those function you can replay with BOOL as return value.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I got it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your `sendRequest:withData:` method returning a BOOL indicating success/failure, it would be better for your `RequestHandler` to have a delegate. It could then let its delegate know about the success/failure/whatever else when the asynchronous request has finished, instead of trying to return this information from the `sendRequest:withData:` method (which, as you've found out, doesn't work so well).

So, you could define you delegate protocol something like this (just as an example - you might want to include some more information in these):

```
@protocol RequestHandlerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)requestHandlerSuccessfullyCompletedRequest:(RequestHandler *)sender;
- (void)requestHandlerFailedToCompletedRequest:(RequestHandler *)sender;

@end
```

Then, give your RequestHandler a delegate property of something that conforms to this protocol:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<RequestHandlerDelegate> delegate;
```

(Make sure you set something as the delegate!)

Then, when your asynchronous request completes, you can send your delegate the appropriate message, e.g.:

```
[self.delegate requestHandlerSuccessfullyCompletedRequest:self];
```

You'll need to implement the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods in `RequestHandler` (from your code, I assume you've already done that), or, if your are targeting iOS 7+, you could take a look at `NSURLSession` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using NSURLConnection with delegate methods you can use `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest` block in your code. In the example you can check connection error and compare status codes.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourURLHere.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *rspreportStatus, NSData *datareportStatus, NSError *e)
{

    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)rspreportStatus;
    int code = [httpResponse statusCode];

    if (e == nil && code == 200)
    {
        // SUCCESS
    } else {
        // NOT SUCCESS
    }
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also check by logging this returnString.

```
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSArray *arrpicResult = [returnString JSONValue];
```

Comment: I am sending an asynchronous request

Comment: Ok use this 
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            }];